# how to minimize DTAExecutionHost.exe for coded UI tests

Tags: tfs, automated-tests

We are using TFS2015 VNext Run functional tests tasks to run our coded UI tests in VMs.

Our Code UI tests click controls on UI, and somehow the command shell of  DTAExecutionHost.exe was in "Select" state which prevent the test run from finishing.

We had to log into the VM and manually un-select the DTAExecutionHost.exe to let the test run finish.

Any idea how to minimize the windows to prevent it being clicked by UI tests? Or if any workarounds to avoid the issue?

Thank you!

Angel

Comment: What the "Select state" mean? Does other Code UI project have this issue? Could you please share a project to onedrive?

Comment: If you open a command shell, then click on it, it will show as "Select" on the left top corner, this means the command is freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue by minimize all windows right after Test Agent being configured.